# Update Jenkins from a war file

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, war

I have a machine with Ubuntu 12.04 and have installed Jenkins ver. 1.424.6 using apt-get based on *[this guide*](http://www.mabishu.com/blog/2012/04/17/setting-up-jenkins-in-ubuntu-precise-12-04-for-php-projects/), but there is a new version:

```
New version of Jenkins (1.447.2) is available for download (changelog).
```

If I press download, I get a `jenkins.war` file... but how do I use that for upgrading my current installation? or is that not possible before the apt repositories gets updated?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You can overwrite the existing `jenkins.war` file with the new one and then restart Jenkins.

This file is usually located in `/usr/share/jenkins`.

If this is not the case for your system, in `Manage Jenkins -> System Information`, it will display the path to the `.war` file under `executable-war`.

Comment: On my machine its located in /usr/share/jenkins/. After copying and restarting with "service jenkins restart" it still shows the old version and suggest an update - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about consistency of configuration files after the upgrade? Do you need to set up the whole thing again? Do they support backward compatibility?

Comment: @DEnysS. it'll keep all your configurations.  I removed the existing war file and moved the new one from Downloads to /usr/share/jenkins and it worked perfectly. (Aptitude didn't show an update for jenkins)

Comment: +1 This helped me out alot, because the current version on Ubuntu is 1.6 while the war version is 2.4. Its a huge difference in look and feel and plugin availability. So this helped me out alot. Was worried I was going to have to install tomcat and do it the hard way.

Comment: step by step of @bcmcfc 's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46733405/1404135

Comment: /usr/lib/jenkins

Comment: In my ubunty jenkins the war file is located at `/usr/share/java/jenkins.war`

Answer (score 47):

```
#on ubuntu, in /usr/share/jenkins:

sudo service jenkins stop
sudo mv jenkins.war jenkins.war.old
sudo wget https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/latest/jenkins.war
sudo service jenkins start
```

Comment: Great! Last stable link is also useful: https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/stable/latest/jenkins.war

Comment: Best Practice, easy to do. Thanks for this answer

Comment: Phew! You helped me from getting a heart attack in the middle of the night with our Jenkins forcing us to upgrade and not running any of its plugins

Comment: I think you don't need to stop service first, you could just use "restart" after replacing the ".war" file

Answer (score 34):

If you have installed Jenkins via apt-get, you should also update Jenkins via apt-get to avoid future problems. Updating should work via "apt-get update" and then "apt-get upgrade".

For details visit the following URL:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu

Comment: +1 b/c you never know what Ubuntu changed about the Jenkins configuration. Adding to this: http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/ provides updated packages installable via apt-get directly from the project.

Comment: No need to update jenkins from war file if you do that mentioned above. I think this is the better way on Ubuntu.

Comment: If you previously installed jenkins with apt-get but through the default Ubuntu package repository (i.e. without pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian), you have to remove the default Ubuntu packages before installing the new one `sudo apt-get remove jenkins jenkins-common` then `sudo apt-get install jenkins`. If you do not do that, the update will fail in a `trying to overwrite '/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war', which is also in package jenkins-common 1.424.6+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1`

Answer (score 13):

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

by far the easiest way to upgrade on linux, works like a charm everytime.

Comment: Similar on CentOS by the way, `yum update jenkins` should do it.

Answer (score 6):

when you open the Jenkins panel it will show available package from their latest version. you can download it via *wget* command in the server.after download the latest package you should take .war backup file.

**Eg-: wget http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/2.205/jenkins.war**

Jenkins war file path for Ubuntu - /usr/share/jenkins/

Jenkins war file path for centos - /usr/lib/jenkins/

after taking backup overwrite the war file and restart the jenkins service.

Ubuntu - service jenkins restart ,
centos - systemctl restart jenkins.service

Answer (score 4):

Though I wouldn't consider this as a valid answer to OP's question, I'd still emphasize that the best way to deploy Jenkins (and likely most if not all libraries/packages/software) on Ubuntu is to leverage aptitude (or apt-get) management system.

It is documented here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu (notice that if you want to use the LTS build, hit on this repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian-stable/)

So if by any chance you actually did use this approach, you'd simply do a `apt-get upgrade jenkins`

Comment: In theory you're right but that doesn't work when upgrading from the stock install.  After installation of the latest package it is starting up but giving a 503 error.  I followed the procedure written there and I had to apply Matthieu Rouget's solution in order to get a consistent pkg state.

Answer (score 2):

We run jenkins from the .war file with the following command.

```
java -Xmx2500M -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=3333 --prefix=/jenkins
```

You can even run the command from the ~/Downloads directory

Answer (score 2):

I use this groovy script to download new war file

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

class ThreadHelper{
    static done = false;
    static starttime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    static synchronized printx (message) {    printf ("%5s seconds: %20s",(System.currentTimeMillis()-starttime)/1000.0 , message); println("") }
    def download(address)
    {
    def filename = new File(System.getenv()['CI_HOME'] + '/' + address.tokenize("/")[-1])
    println(filename.getCanonicalPath())
    def file = new FileOutputStream(filename)
    def out = new BufferedOutputStream(file)
    out << new URL(address).openStream()
    out.close()
    done=true;
    }

}

println("executing from ... "+ new File(".").getCanonicalPath())

def counter = new AtomicInteger();
    th = Thread.start {
    while(!ThreadHelper.done) {
    sleep 1000
    counter.incrementAndGet()
    print '.'
    }
}

th2 = Thread.start { new ThreadHelper().download("http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/war/latest/jenkins.war") }
th.join()
th2.join()

ThreadHelper.printx('done')
```

And another script shutsdown tomcat - copies the war and restarts it

We host it on windows 2008 and tomcat, I use sc query, sc config, sc stop, sc start to manage windows services

```
    set warname=jenkins

if '%name%' == 'trak' set warname=trak

pushd .
if '%name%'=='' goto badname
if '%warname%'=='' goto badname

if '%ci_home%'=='' goto badcihome

REM =====================================================
REM stop windows service
sc stop %name%

REM sleep for 5 seconds see http:\\stackoverflow.com\questions\1672338\how-to-sleep-for-5-seconds-in-windowss-command-prompt-or-dos
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 > nul

rem replace forward slash with backward slash
set tomcat_dir=%ci_home:/=\%\instances\tomcat7-%name%

REM Create sub directory called bak-yymmdd-hhmmss
REM where yymmdd-hhmmss is a date-time stamp like 120601-142907

set hh=%time:~0,2%

REM Since there is no leading zero for times before 10 am, have to put in
REM a zero when this is run before 10 am.

if "%time:~0,1%"==" " set hh=0%hh:~1,1%

set yymmdd_hhmmss=%date:~12,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%-%hh%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

set backupdir=bak-%yymmdd_hhmmss%

REM =====================================================
md %tomcat_dir%\logs\%backupdir%

cd %tomcat_dir%\logs

dir bak*
echo "nothing-to-log" >> force.log

REM move command will fail if there is nothing to move hence the force log statement above

call move *.* %backupdir%

REM =====================================================
rmdir %tomcat_dir%\webapps\%name% /q/s

echo f|xcopy %ci_home%\%warname%.war %tomcat_dir%\webapps\%name%.war /y

REM TODO===== something about jenkins plugins

REM =====================================================
cd "%tomcat_dir%\bin"
call catalina version

echo =====================================================
echo ====== removing %name%
call service remove %name%

echo =====================================================
echo ====== installing %name%
call service install %name%

echo on

REM setting service to start automatically, note that space before the word auto IS REQUIRED
sc config %name% start= auto

REM =====================================================
sc start %name%

popd

exit 0

goto done

:badname
echo 'name required - this will be used as windows service name as well'
pause
exit 1

:badcihome
echo 'CI home env var required - ci_home'
pause
exit 1

:done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu

Once installed like this, you can update to the later version of Jenkins (when it comes out) by running the following commands:
-------
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jenkins
-------
(aptitude or apt-get doesn't make any difference.)
What does this package do?
Jenkins will be launched as a daemon up on start. See /etc/init.d/jenkins for more details.
The 'jenkins' user is created to run this service.
Log file will be placed in /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log. Check this file if you are troubleshooting Jenkins.
/etc/default/jenkins will capture configuration parameters for the launch like e.g JENKINS_HOME
By default, Jenkins listen on port 8080. Access this port with your browser to start configuration.
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be done in two ways

1. Directly download the .war file and replace it with the existing one.
2. update directly from ubuntu

**1st Method**

If you are not able to find jenkins war file in standard path, you can goto Manage Jenkins → System Information, it will display the path to the .war file.

The common location of Jenkins war file on the ubuntu server is:

```
/usr/share/jenkins
```

Jump to jenkins home directory

```
cd /usr/share/jenkins
```

Stop the jenkins server

```
sudo service jenkins stop
```

Move existing jenkins war file

```
sudo mv jenkins.war jenkins.war.old
```

Download latest jenkins war file

```
sudo wget https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/latest/jenkins.war
```

Start the Jenkins server

```
sudo service jenkins start
```

Everything should be good now.

**Troubleshooting steps**

If you are running jenkins using root permissions, (which you should not be doing), you need to change the jenkins.war permissions.

```
$ sudo chown root:root jenkins.war
```

You can optionally restart the jenkins server using below command:

$ sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins restart

**2nd Method**

On ubuntu, you can also try the below two commands to update everything:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install jenkins --fix-missing
```

Answer (score 1):

Mine is installed under /usr/share/jenkins
I thought it was installed via apt-get so might want to check there as well.

Ubuntu 12.04.1

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want to install the x11-common and other components that come bundled in the apt-get install approach, so I just downloaded the .war file and ran the command Francois mentioned. That worked nicely, but you have to write your own daemon script with that approach. Full details here: http://strem.in/stream/9488/Using-the-war-file-for-jenkins-ci

Answer (score 1):

To Upgrade Jenkins WAR file, follow the steps below:

- Stop Jenkins server using command: `systemctl stop jenkins`
- Go to Jenkins war location: ex: `/usr/lib/jenkins`
- Take a backup from jenkins.war: `mv jenkins.war jenkins.war_bkp`
- Download Jenkins using wget or curl command: 
  `wget http://updates.jenkinsci.org/download/war/(version)/jenkins.war`
- Starting Jenkins server using command: `systemctl start jenkins`
- Check Jenkins server status using command: `systemctl status jenkin`

Answer (score 0):

- In the latest version of Jenkins, the `jenkins.war` file location has been changed.
- `updatedb && locate jenkins.war` command can be used to check the new path which is: `/usr/share/java/`.
- Replace the old `.war` file with the new one under `/usr/share/java/` directory and restart the Jenkins to upgrade it.