# Jenkins failed to restart after updating through war on Ubuntu

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to update jenkins from 2.60.1 to 2.67 through war. For that purpose I have downloaded war for required version from this [link](https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/), I also referred this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062335/update-jenkins-from-a-war-file) on stack overflow to follow the procedure.But when I try to restart the jenkins after completing process, it is failing to restart. Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: where can I check detailed exception, console is just showing me -  * Restarting Jenkins Continuous Integration Server jenkins              [failed]

Comment: default logs should be made available in /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log

Comment: Jenkins now requires Java 8. Is that installed (and the default JRE)?

Comment: @StephenKing yes it's installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, the issue was with permissions of war file I copied into jenkins war directory. I have given basic permissions i.e.

> rw-r--r-- 1 root root 71617234 Jun 30 11:24 jenkins.war

and then tried to restart jenkins , it worked appropriately. Previously somehow these permissions were not there for the war file.