# Move Hudson Server directly from one Windows PC to another Windows PC

Tags: hudson

I have a Hudson server on one PC, and I need to move it to another PC.

I want to do this right the first time without messing up a bunch of things.  I've found in my Googling a Stack Overflow question and answer for moving Jenkins [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724939/how-to-move-jenkins-from-one-pc-to-another).

I am wary to follow those instructions for Hudson because:

1. There might be a subtle but significant difference between Hudson and Jenkins since the time that they forked from each other that causes complications;
2. I'm dealing with **Windows 7**, not Linux;
3. I want to know if I can just move Hudson ***directly*** from one PC to another, without having to install and reconfigure Hudson on the target PC first (as per the Jenkins instructions).

So my question is, can I move my Hudson installation directly without installing a fresh Hudson on the target PC first?  If so, what are the steps?

Comment: If you are running Hudson as a Windows service, then Yes, you must install first and then copy the old Hudson installation. If you are using a TomCat servlet or something similar, then you may not have to do the full install.

Comment: I am running it as a Windows Service... but couldn't I just copy the Hudson installation directory, and then set it up as a Windows Service on the target PC later?

Comment: I believe the installer does more than just install the service (It may set some registry settings etc...) so I don't think that would be a good idea.