# Jenkins migration to new server

Tags: jenkins

For some organizational reasons we have to move Jenkins to new servers. As we are on a old version so a updated is also need on same time. What are things we should consider. Also not sure if we need to configure all jobs in new instance manually or there is faster way to clone them from existing instance. We have around 300 jobs, one master and 7 slaves. We need to set up three masters, one with four slaves and two with three slaves. 300 jobs will split between three masters depending upon there category.

Thanks !!

Comment: I think it's rather question to SU not SO. SO is question/answer site.

Comment: I did not follow what are you trying to say and reson for -ve vote.

Comment: Part of your question is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724939/how-to-move-jenkins-from-one-pc-to-another.  I suggest you move to server retaining  current jenkin version.  Upgrading jenkins version should be another project.  This avoids risk of some jobs broken due to newer plugins

Comment: Just in case you want to migrate jobs selectively, you can use import jobs plugin. This probably handles dependencies on plugins.

Comment: Thanks Jayan. Import job plugin is a good tip.

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to move Jenkins jobs to 3 different servers with their own plugins - I would:

1. Create those 3 instances of Jenkins and configure them separately. Make sure that new/resetup slaves are ready to handle new requirements.
2. Create 3 separate lists of jobs (split from the original list).
3. Determine which jobs should be run by which Jenkins
4. Install all the common plugins used by all/most jobs on all 3 Jenkins instances.
5. Go to the original ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs and

   ```
   tar cvfz < jobs_list > jobs.tgz
   ```

   3 times, separately for each new Jenkins instance
6. Finally unpack the job archives to corresponding new ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs directories.
7. Run tests and install missing plugins after that, if needed. In my opinion, access permissions should be set separately on each Jenkins instance.

Comment: Thanks Jan. should i need to tar all jobs or indecent specific only ?

Comment: The ones you actually need. Jobs can be moved around this way or backed up easily. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins is one place to read about this.