# Exporting Jenkins exact settings / plugins from server 1 to server 2

Tags: jenkins, server

I read about archiving JENKINS_HOME in the wiki
(https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins)

but didnt exactly tell me how to archive it, was looking for any type of assistance

I found this

[How to move Jenkins from one PC to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724939/how-to-move-jenkins-from-one-pc-to-another)

which is great but have some open ended questions and cant comment due to my low rank.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to zip your Jenkins home folder and copy it to the new server (the new Jenkins instance must be stopped).

Next, starts the new Jenkins instance and check you can access the new URL.

Once Jenkins is started, go to the Manage Jenkins/Configure system menu and update the Jenkins URL:

[image]

It should be enough to move your Jenkins stuff to the new server.

Comment: thanks for that, another question, so i just installed jenkins on server two and obviously the jenkins folder gets populated, what do I do with all that If   I am going to use my jenkins directory from server 1

Comment: When you start the Jenkins application on the server 2 for the first time, Jenkins will populate the jenkins home folder with the default configuration files. Please stop Jenkins on the server 2, do a backup of these files, remove them, and copy the content from the server 1. Next, restart Jenkins on the server 2.