# Can I upgrade Jenkins at the same time as migrating to a new host?

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins master running Jenkins ver. 1.585.
I have a new server thatI want to migrate Jenkins to.
I'd also like to upgrade Jenkins to the latest stable version.

Can I install the new server with the desired version or do I have to use the same version and upgrade it after migrating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following process worked for me:

1. Upgrade the old master: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Automated+Upgrade
2. Upgrade the plugins
3. Move the master: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8725480/643210