# Jenkins: How do a complete backup for data and configuration for a specific Folder or project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

For backup reasons we need resolve the following scenario:

Computer `A` where **Jenkins** is installed, it manages many projects arranged through **Folders**, such as: `Project X`, `Project Y` etc.
The point is: each project is managed through a `Jenkins`' **Folder**.

Where for each `Folder` or *project*, it has `Views` and it contains the `Job`s included according a view and all of them were previously executed.

Computer `B` is available and `Jenkins` is installed.

What is the best approach to do a backup from Computer A for a **specific** `Folder` containing all the configuration about `Views` and all the `Jobs` executed previously? ... In some way we need the computer B be the *new* A, keeping all the *complete* log history from the beginning for all the previous executed `Job`s and keeping the `Views` configuration.

Some special plugin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move Jenkins from one PC to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724939/how-to-move-jenkins-from-one-pc-to-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `JENKINS_HOME` location (normally from `.jenkins`), go to the `jobs` directory and copy and paste the project directory in the *other* computer in the same location: `jobs` directory (`JENKINS_HOME` location).

**Note**: I have a project directory within the `jobs` directory because through `Jenkins` a **Folder** was created for a custom project to contain all the `Views` and `Jobs` related.