# How to transfer Jenkins plugins and settings

Tags: jenkins, plugins, migration

I got a task in which i have to setup new jenkins server and copy jobs,plugins,settings etc from existing server. 
So far I copied all the jobs but how to **import all the plugins and settings** we have on jenkins didn't find the answer.

If there is any plugin that will do the work will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

There is this simple solution for that.

1. Stop your existing Jenkins server and also the new Jenkins server that you have installed.
2. Create a archive file of all the contents in the `JENKINS_HOME` folder of your exiting Jenkins instance.
3. Now, extract that archive file to the `JENKINS_HOME` directory of your new Jenkins instance and then launch your new Jenkins.
4. Now in your new Jenkins instance go to `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System` and find `Jenkins Location` section and then under the`Jenkins URL` field change the URL that points to the new Jenkins instance.
   [image]

And you are done :)

Answer (score 1):

For similar kind of task I wrote python script to migrate plugins & jobs from one Jenkins instance to another using Jenkins Rest API. You can find the detailed steps in this post [How to move Jenkins from one PC to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724939/how-to-move-jenkins-from-one-pc-to-another/44701594#44701594)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already created a new Jenkins service, and you want to copy all plugins from a `path/to/old/JENKINS_HOME` to your newly `path/to/new/JENKINS_HOME`.

#### Download [Jenkins plugin installation manager tool](https://github.com/jenkinsci/plugin-installation-manager-tool/releases)

#### Export The Plugins To A File

to export a `yaml` file (for example `plugins.yaml`), run:

> WARNING: in this implementation we removed the version for each plugin, so **jenkins will install the latest versions of the plugins**.

```
java -jar jenkins-plugin-manager-*.jar --war /path/to/jenkins.war --plugin-download-directory "path/to/new/JENKINS_HOME/plugins" -l --output yaml | sed '/source:/d' | sed '/version:/d' | tee path/to/new/JENKINS_HOME/plugins-from-old-installation.yaml
```

#### Import The Plugins From A File

then to install the list of plugins from the exported file (for example `plugins.yaml`):

> WARNING: in this implementation we allow the security rules that were allowed in the old installation, with the `--hide-security-warnings` option.

```
java -jar jenkins-plugin-manager-*.jar --war /usr/share/java/jenkins.war --plugin-download-directory "path/to/old/JENKINS_HOME/plugins" --plugin-file path/to/new/JENKINS_HOME/plugins-from-old-installation.yaml --hide-security-warnings
```

##### Copy All The Plugins' Configurations

> WARNING: in this implementation we copy all the plugins' configurations, as well as **all the configurations of the entire system that may not be relevant to these plugins (such as credentials... etc...)!**

Copy all the `.xml` files that are in the root directory of the old `JENKINS_HOME` to the new `JENKINS_HOME`. Like so:

```
ls 'path/to/old/JENKINS_HOME' | grep '.*.\xml$' | xargs -I{} cp {} 'path/to/new/JENKINS_HOME'
```

After you installed the plugins, you need to restart the jenkins service for them to take an effect:

```
sudo systemctl restart jenkins
```