# How to Move jenkins with all plugin,Jobs and all other configuration to another server in cloud

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, ansible, migration

Need expert help on this.I have a task to move on premises jenkins to GCP Cloud server and need exact replica of the Jenkins.Can someone help me on this.I want all plugins ,configuration and jobs to be present in new GCP machine and it should be exact replica of the on premise jenkins server so that we can shut down the on premise machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this instructions that seems to be correct:

Following the Jenkins wiki, you'll have to:

- Install a fresh Jenkins instance on the new server
- Be sure the old and the new Jenkins instances are stopped
- Archive all the content of the JENKINS_HOME of the old Jenkins
  instance
- Extract the archive into the new JENKINS_HOME directory
- Launch the new Jenkins instance
- Do not forget to change documentation/links to your new instance of
  Jenkins :)
- Do not forget to change the owner of the new Jenkins files : chown -R
  jenkins:jenkins $JENKINS_HOME

JENKINS_HOME is by default located in ~/.jenkins on a Linux installation, yet to exactly find where it is located, go on the http://your_jenkins_url/configure page and check the value of the first parameter: Home directory; this is the JENKINS_HOME.

You can review the details in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724939/how-to-move-jenkins-from-one-pc-to-another), an also this [link](https://medium.com/@fnote/jenkins-moving-from-one-server-to-another-9a5dea1fa3f2) with 3 methods that you could use.